# Compile Finite State Machine to UML(-like) Diagram

Tags: fsm, scxml, draw.io

Every Python developer knows tools like [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/). You write some text in a markup language, write `make` in the shell and let some compilers do their job. In the end you get beautiful HTML or PDF.

I am looking for something like that, just for Finite State Machines, e.g. I put [SCXML](http://www.w3.org/TR/scxml/) into a file (with a GUI or manually with VIM as I desire) start a compiler and out comes a picture file format that i can use however I please and that looks good even if I don't know what I am doing. Example:

```
$ vim my-fsm.scxml
$ scxml2svg my-fsm.scxml
writing file...
finished writing my-fsm.svg
$
```

The closest I got so far is using various Eclipse plugins (years ago, dislike huge IDEs), [draw.io](https://www.draw.io) or what I am using now: [Umlet](http://www.umlet.com/). Even Umlet has problems, though. For example it doesn't support the workflow I am used to (write text files, start compiler, see beautiful result). The results are often also suboptimal, because the engine is actually quite simple. But everywhere I look for a more useful alternative ([python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/FiniteStateMachine), [other SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492980/what-are-the-best-python-finite-state-machine-implementations), [tools](https://github.com/jroxendal/PySCXML)) I still don't find a simple compiler.

Now I would be really happy if anybody would know such a compiler. If not possible a FOSS GUI editors with PNG/SVG export would also be okay.

Comment: like Ragel (http://www.complang.org/ragel/) but using SCXML as input data ?

Comment: Ah other input data is also fine. just fsm-source-to-image compiling is important. Ragel looks quite good. Do you know more like that? Also feel free to add that as a complete answer and edit the question to match!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GraphViz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphviz) has a [file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_%28graph_description_language%29) which can be written manually and compiled to different picture formats.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote some tools to do this: http://goo.gl/V97ft

Comment: yes, great! For my thesis I am set to plantuml currently, but your tooling makes more sense in the long run. Maybe you can offer shell support in some way?

Comment: Should be possible with PhantomJS. I'll look into it.

Comment: I added command-line PDF generation capability to scxml-viz. Give it a try and let me know if you have any trouble with it: https://github.com/jbeard4/scxml-viz